# Promise type in typescript using generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, promise

I have the following DEFAULT_VALUE for context API respecting an Interface, which has a promise void using generics.

So what is the correct signature to create a default value promise and get away with this error?

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrJyS.png)

Comment: Post code not images. Also the first parameter of `Promise` is supposed to be a funcition that receives resolve/reject parameters https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise . You might be looking for `Promise.resolve` if you want to resolve a promise with a value

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am totally new here so, next time I will make a better post with codes. By te way, I "resolved" it including a callback returning a Promise.resolve(). Thanks for tip.